# Images are not loading in android 5.0 using picasso library

Tags: android, picasso

I am working on demo application in which I am using Picasso library v2.5.2. It is working fine on all android operating system version, but not in lollipop.

**Image whose size is 130KB which is not loading for me. Images whose size is less are loading correctly.**

Here is my code for downloading bitmap and set on imageview.

```
target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {}
};

Picasso.with(this).load(URL).into(target);
```

I'm not sure what extra stuff I have to do with this so that I will work on lollipop also or this is bug in lib ?

Answer (score 14):

It's a known problem. The problem is that Picasso keeps a weak reference for the `Target`. To get it working you need to make it strong, by storing a `Target` as a tag of view, for example.

```
target = new Target() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
        if(bitmap != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {}
    };

imageView.setTag(target);
Picasso.with(this).load(URL).into((Target) imageView.getTag());
```

**EDIT:**

I suggest you to use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide), it's very similar to Picasso, and also recommended by Google. And as you can see in the end of [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57578), the original developer solves this BitmapFactory problem by using extra buffer.

Comment: I am not sure what changes need to do. I am using picasso lib. How to resolve. can you please share a bit of code of it..

Comment: I tried Glide also but facing same issue there also :(

Comment: Picasso is not working even while setting target. Glide is working perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use a `Target` if you only need to load the image into the `ImageView`? Just use this:

```
    Picasso.with(this).load(URL).into(imageView, new Callback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess()
        {
            //Dimiss progress dialog here
        }

        @Override
        public void onError()
        {
            //And here
        }
    });
```

For documentation look [here](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: I'm dismissing progress dialog once image has been loaded. I had that line of code in `onBitmapLoaded`

Comment: @Williams see my edit. You can use a `Callback` for this. I would suggest you only use a `Target` if you really need to use it.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try this & will update you for same.

Comment: @Williams what's not working? I just used the same thing today on lollipop. What device do you have? And what specific version. 5.0?

Comment: I am testing on nexus 6, Image whose size is 130KB or more which is not loading for me. Images whose size is less are loading correctly.

Comment: @Williams can you give me a URL and the exact method you're calling? I'll test it out what could be going wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79564/discussion-between-williams-and-kevin-van-mierlo).

Answer (score 0):

```
        Picasso.with(this).load("http://webneel.com/wallpaper/sites/default/files/images/04-2013/island-beach-scenery-wallpaper.jpg").placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).fit().into(imageView, new Callback()      { 
    @Override public void onSuccess() 
    {
     } 
   @Override public void onError() 
   {
    }
     });
```

fit() will help you to load image.And use   android:adjustViewBounds="true" in your ImageView in xml.