# Android - Picasso misses pictures sometimes

Tags: android, picasso, bitmapfactory, imagedownload

I am using Picasso library for images downloading using the following code, I've to load many pictures in a loop by resizing them and transforming to circular. Sometimes images are successfully loaded and sometimes onError method is called instead of onSuccess in Callback. And i get this error `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null Error`. When i uninstall the app then after reinstalling images are loaded successfully mostly. What is the problem exactly and kindly suggest any solution.

Code:

```
int dp = (int) resources.getDimension(R.dimen.marker_pic_size);
    Picasso.with(context).load(profilePic_url)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .resize(dp, dp)
            .into(tempView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {
                Log.d("usm_onSuccess", profilePic_url);   
                  }

                @Override
                public void onError() {
                    Log.d("usm_onError", profilePic_url);
                }
            });
```

Comment: I am also facing this problem? Any ANswer would be Life Saver !

Answer (score 1):

By the use of [Target](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/Target.html) it may solve you problem.

```
target = new Target() {
@Override
public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {}

@Override
public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, LoadedFrom arg1) {
    if(bitmap != null) {
        tempView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}

@Override
public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {}
};
```

...

```
int dp = (int) resources.getDimension(R.dimen.marker_pic_size);
    Picasso.with(context).load(profilePic_url)
            .transform(new CircleTransform())
            .resize(dp, dp)
            .into(target);
tempView.setTag(target);
```

It is know [issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57578).You may also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503625/images-are-not-loading-in-android-5-0-using-picasso-library) to get more idea.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still getting 'SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null Error' for some pictures